# I have a clash between python modules pynotify, gtk and wx.richtext is there a way to debug this?

Tags: python, wxpython, python-import

I have a large script which uses pynotify, gtk and wx.richtext amongst others and there is some clash between these 3 that causes a segmentation fault if I attempt to use a RichTextCtrl. I have painstakingly hacked out each import from the script and narrowed it down to gtk and pynotify, interfering with richtext. Is there some method of tracking down what is causing the segmentation fault?
The following script demonstrates the problem.
Comment out the imports to pynotify and gtk and it works fine, leave them in it falls over.
This is using python 2.7 wxpython2.8 linux Mint 17 64bit

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
import pynotify
import gtk 
import wx.richtext as rt
########################################################################
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    ''' TextEditMixin allows any column to be edited. '''

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        rows = [("Ford", "Taurus", "1996", "Blue"),
                ("Nissan", "370Z", "2010", "Green"),
                ("Porche", "911", "2009", "Red")
                ]
        self.list_ctrl = EditableListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)

        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Make")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Model")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Year")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, "Color")

        index = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, row[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, row[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, row[2])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 3, row[3])
            index += 1
        self.other = rt.RichTextCtrl(self, -1, "Hello", size=(50,30))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.other, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Editable List Control")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Importing both `wx` *and* `gtk` does not sound like the best idea...

Comment: `SIGSEGV` usually indicates you either called something you shouldn't call or one of your modules crashed. If it's the latter, you probably have an incompatibility between your modules indeed.

Comment: Also, please read the [WX style guide](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20Style%20Guide). Doing things the right way tends to prevent a lot of trouble.

Comment: Whilst importing wx and gtk may not sound like the best idea in the world, they do function happily together. It is only when I use richtextctrl that the problem occurs. In the example, leave either gtk or pynotify in the mix and the segmentation fault occurs. Is there something in common between gtk and pynotify that I can't see?

Comment: You don't need two GUI toolkits. Their main loops will get entangled in weird ways. Your code example doesn't actually use `gtk` though, so you should just remove it.

Comment: The script provided is just an example, so no it doesn't use gtk nor does it use pynotify, it provides proof of the error. 2 people have now said that using gtk with wx is a bad idea, so why is gtk a module for wx? In the end I removed gtk which was being used to get the path to icon for files based on the mimetype and swapped pynotify for python-notify2 and the richtextctrl now works, so thank you to those who replied. The actual answer remains elusive.